# Vertically Center Navigation UL LI

Tags: css, navigation

I wish to make the all the list items to be centered. or at least 20 pixels from the top.

I have tried negative margin-top but that didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Here is the site. http://freddygonzalez.me/dev/85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to remove `display: inline` and `margin-top` and add the following rules to the `li` elements:

```
float: left;
line-height: 49px;
```

Note that this won't work if a menu item can have two lines of text.

Comment: Technically floats inside an inline element isn't valid. Why not just make the LI elements inline too?

Comment: Because then there's no way to vertically center it.